# how to save specific part of page as image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have create grid using JavaScript and I want to save that grid with some dropped image as a image. here is my [link](http://ushatech.com/customer/Palletized_Material_Handling_Conveyors/build.php?num1=50&num2=50)

Comment: Can't be done from a browser.

Comment: You want to make a screen capture of the dhtmlgoodies_xpPane div?

Comment: @Zakaria  yes I want to save a part of page that is created by jquery.

Comment: @Moumita +1 Interesting... and this is useful for applications

Comment: @Moumita similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193221/screen-grab-with-php-and-or-javascript

Comment: @Moumita This might be useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas#section_9

Comment: @Brandon is it possible to save the grid which one I had create.

Comment: looks like you got response .... if you manage with js give me an update.

Comment: @experimentX still I'm trying , but didn't get any result.those are too much difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you can restrict this usage to browsers using canvas elements, and with firefox extensions -- so firefox in fact, you can load any part of the DOM in a canvas and extract image for the canvas. Basically:

```
canvas = document.getElementById("#acanvas"); 
if (canvas.getContext) {
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawWindow(here_any_part_of_the_DOM_tree_not_only_window);
    var mypng = context.toDataURL();
}
```