# How to save the contents of a div as a image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, screenshot

Basically, I am doing what the heading states, attempting to save the contents of a div as an image.

I plan on making a small online application for the iPad.

One function that is a must is having a 'Save' button that can save the full webpage as an image, and save that image to the iPad's camera roll. I wish to save the full contents of a div, not just the visible area.

I have searched briefly online, but couldn't find much documentation on anything. I found a lot on HTML5 Canvas. Here is some code I put together:

```
<script>
function saveimg()
{
    var c = document.getElementById('mycanvas');
    var t = c.getContext('2d');
    window.location.href = image;

    window.open('', document.getElementById('mycanvas').toDataURL());
}
</script>

<div id="mycanvas">
This is just a test<br />
12344<br />
</div>

<button onclick="saveimg()">Save</button>
```

Although, I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: c.getContext is not a function
```

This application will be built only with HTML, CSS and jQuery (or other Javascript libraries).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take screen shot of a div with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)

Comment: @GlenSwift - Thank you for that, but the example code in that post does not work.

Comment: There are several of this same question ((https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript), (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339490/saving-div-contents-or-canvas-as-image)(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339490/saving-div-contents-or-canvas-as-image)). One way of doing it is using canvas. [Here's a working solution](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). [Here](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/documentation) you can see some working examples of using th

Comment: `c.getContext` isn't a function because `mycanvas` is just a div, not a `canvas` element. Only `canvas`es have a context.

Answer (score 3):

Do something like this:

A `<div>` with ID of `#imageDIV`, another one with ID `#download` and a hidden `<div>` with ID `#previewImage`.

Include the latest version of jquery, and jspdf.debug.js from [the jspdf CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js)

Then add this script:

```
var element = $("#imageDIV"); // global variable
var getCanvas; // global variable
$('document').ready(function(){
  html2canvas(element, {
    onrendered: function (canvas) {
      $("#previewImage").append(canvas);
      getCanvas = canvas;
    }
  });
});
$("#download").on('click', function () {
  var imgageData = getCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  // Now browser starts downloading it instead of just showing it
  var newData = imageData.replace(/^data:image\/png/, "data:application/octet-stream");
  $("#download").attr("download", "image.png").attr("href", newData);
});
```

The div will be saved as a PNG on clicking the `#download`

Comment: onrendered is never executed and therefor getCanvas is undefined

Comment: onrendered is apparently obsolete in html2canvas. Use the `.then` method instead like `html2canvas(element).then(function(canvas){ yourcode();  });

Comment: it worked for me when I gave #download to an anchor tag

Answer (score 1):

What about applying full screen to the element and then taking a print of the screen? You can do all that with html and js only. This is just an idea. I need something similar and I haven't tested it yet.