# How to save div as image without additional libraries?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

My question may be simple:

**Is there a way to save div content as an image(jpg) without additional libraries like "html2canvas" ?**

Thank you in advance!

Comment: asking questions that have answers like YES or NO are not for stackoverflow. anyway...with a minimal search on this site you could've found several answers. see here  for example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311645/download-image-with-javascript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply put, no. There's no native way to capture an element as an image without some third-party script.

HTML2Canvas is also very robust and quite lightweight, apart from errors when handling SVG images!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you **can't do this without a library**.

Anyway you can see several questions on StackOverflow dealing with this subject, if you want to avoid Canvas: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339490/saving-div-contents-or-canvas-as-image).