# Converting Text to Image with another Image in Java Springboot

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have search but unable to find anything suitable for converting text along with logo image to another image or PDF. It would be great if both image and Pdf options are there, Just like Banking website.

```
 model.addAttribute("success_message", "Your Reference number is " + referenceNo + ".\nFund Transfer of Amount " + cl.Money(xxDTO.getAmount())
+ " has been made successfully against " + xxDTO.getAccount()
+ " on " + xxDTO.getTime()
+ " from " + xxDTO.getSendAccountNumber()
+ " for " + session.getAttribute("purposeText"));
```

This is my success message, When funds are transfered, The success messages show on a page inside a div. But I want to add two options there to download as Image or PDF.

How Can I achieve that in Java 11 (Springboot)

I will have to add one static logo at the top and then above text at bottom, and Text format can be changed etc.
For testing purpose, I have created a simple HTML file and added a table inside it. It is a static File. I have addded a button and on button click, I am trying to download PDF, Below is code

```
@requestMapping("/pdf")
    public ResponseEntity<?> getPDF(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {


        /* Create HTML using Thymeleaf template Engine */
        // testingpdf is html view
        String orderHtml = templateEngine.process("testingpdf");

        /* Setup Source and target I/O streams */

        ByteArrayOutputStream target = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        /*Setup converter properties. */
        ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
        converterProperties.setBaseUri("http://localhost:8080");

        /* Call convert method */
        HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(orderHtml, target, converterProperties);

        /* extract output as bytes */
        byte[] bytes = target.toByteArray();


        /* Send the response as downloadable PDF */

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(bytes);
    }
```

POM FILE

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

The above is already in my pom.xml but these import are not working.

```
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;
```

Comment: For creating and manipulating PDF, you can use iText library

Comment: You can also convert your div that contains your message and logo into a PDF file using javascript

Comment: how about into img?

Comment: The same thing as PDF

Comment: will this work in springboot framework? I am very new to java and springboot, How can i install iText Library?

Comment: Yes you can check my solution

Comment: OK im gonna try iText

Comment: Ok, you will find a lot of example and tuto, good luck

Comment: I have updated the question with code, can u check what is the actual error, its gives error.'

Comment: Cannot reoslve symbol ResponseEntity

Comment: You should add the ResponseEntity to import

Comment: IM following this tutorial with MCV https://springhow.com/spring-boot-pdf-generation/

Comment: use this `import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;`

Comment: Thansk Im having issues on ConverterProperties, I have added dependency in pom for itext and html2pdf and also added these two lines at start of file `
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConverterProperties;
import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.HtmlConverter;` but still ConverterPropteries is not accessible

Comment: What do you mean by not accessible ? did you add this in your pom. xml `<dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>html2pdf</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>kernel</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.12</version>
        </dependency>`

Comment: This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Mar 31 22:22:19 PKT 2021
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
No message available

Comment: Gives me this above error and also it doesn't look like it is imported like other ones.

Comment: Do I have to install these libraries? I have only added in pom.xml

Comment: No just add them to pom.xml

Comment: I have already added them to but when i type import com.itextpdf.html2pdf.ConvertProperties, it doesn't appear, i feel like they are not added. I have updated pom.xml in above question, check

Comment: When you update the pom.xml you must have internet to downloaded by maven

Comment: I have only copy the code and pasted in pom.xml and saved the file, how will it download automatically? is there any command to do it or something else?

Comment: `Error:(24, 29) java: package com.itextpdf.html2pdf does not exist`

Comment: mvn clean install

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230605/discussion-between-med-elgarnaoui-and-asfandyar-khan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iText library for creating and manipulating PDF, you can find documentation in this [link](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/api-documentation) about itext.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
    <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.13.2</version>
</dependency>
```

There other way to do that by :

- Converting a div to PDF using [jsPDF](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF), the question was already asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17293135/download-a-div-in-a-html-page-as-pdf-using-javascript)

From @ilyes you can use jsPDF as:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function (element, renderer) {
        return true;
    }
};

$('#cmd').click(function () {
    doc.fromHTML($('#divtoBepdf').html(), 15, 15, {
        'width': 170,
            'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
});
```

- Converting a div to image(Canva), take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581379/how-to-save-the-contents-of-a-div-as-a-image), this [one,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339490/saving-div-contents-or-canvas-as-image).

There other way to do that ...