# Screen Capture Application in Javascript or Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my application I wanted Screen capture button that will capture the screen. I wanted to make this application using javascript or jquery .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Screencapture from the browser using Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/181622/screencapture-from-the-browser-using-javascript) - or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Comment: Here's a solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701798/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-web-page

Comment: @Deepak that's not a real solution - getting `innerHTML` and rebuilding it on the server to make a screenshot is not a *valid* solution

Answer (score 1):

it is not possible with simple javascript, but there are some solutions:

- [active-x control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)
- [html5](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)