# How to capture browser activity into a video file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, video, browser, video-capture

I want to capture the activity in a browser for testing purpose. Is it possible using javascript? Is there any other possibilities?

I want to record screen once a record button is pressed and stopped when a stop button is pressed.

Comment: duplicate--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7618368/how-to-capture-the-screen-using-javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9156939/screen-capture-application-in-javascript-or-jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CrazyEgg:** It lets you check your visitor activity across multiple domains and is quite easy to setup. Free account (offers following features

- Heatmap Analysis – Visual representation of where people clicked on your site. This tells you what’s hot and what’s not, so you can make changes that matter.
- Confetti – This will help you dig a little deeper into visitor activity and refine them based on referrers, operating system, browsers etc.
- Overlay – helps you understand how many times a link was clicked? What are the ‘hot’ links in your site?
- List – Helps you understand activities per element (for instance, how many visitors used the ‘search box’, clicked on an image.

**ClickDensity:** offers pretty much similar features as Crazyegg, and there are few features that differentiates it from the rest:

- Surprise areas – Are people clicking on areas where they shouldn’t? (unlinked logo?). Similarly, what are the unpopular areas/links in your site?
- Precise Heatmaps – Unlike many other services, ClickDensity heatmaps are very precise and it’s really easy to compare different sections/components.

-Hover maps – displays usage data for individual items on your pages. All clickable items on the page are highlighted, and can be individually activated to show the number of visitors that clicked on them, and other statistics.

- Page stats : You can follow any link on your site and check the stat of that page (even for free accounts).

**UserFly:** How about watching a video of user activity on the site? Watching where they click, how they scroll? Their mouse movement etc? How do they consume content?

Userfly essentially lets you track visitor activity on the site and stores the videos in your account. We have been using Userfly for quite sometime and really like the service (though there are a lot of features suggestions for the team).

**WebVisor:** is a module Yandex Metrica which allows you to view your visitors to the activated form of videos.

You can watch actions such as mouse movement, clicks, scrolling de page, form filling and selecting / copying text.

Reference URL: 
http://www.pluggd.in/track-website-visitor-activity-services-tools-to-use-297/

http://existenceweb.fr/wordpress/webvisor-enregistrez-lactivite-de-vos-visiteurs-en-video/?lang=en

Comment: I am sorry I made a mistake here, you wanted it for testing purpose but I posted something which does it for visitors.

Comment: UserFly meets my need to some extent... But they are not accepting new registrations. Is any possibility of getting some javascript like **Userfly**

Comment: let me google up..!
Can below reference will be of some help?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280516/alternatives-to-userfly-com

http://www.usefulusability.com/24-usability-testing-tools/

http://www.clicktale.com

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Jing?  Our QA often use that app for capturing screencasts of browser bugs.  [http://www.techsmith.com/jing-features.html]