# How to set the background image of a html 5 canvas to .png image

Tags: html, canvas, background-image

I would like to know how it is possible to set the background image of a canvas to a .png file. I do not want to add the image in the back of the canvas and make the canvas transparent.

I want the user to be able to actually draw on that canvas with the background being the .png image so that I can extract it later as a .png with the drawings that the user made.

Answer (score 36):

As shown in [this example](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_cssbg.html), you can apply a background to a `canvas` element through CSS and this background will not be considered part  the image, e.g. when fetching the contents through `toDataURL()`.

Here are the contents of the example, for Stack Overflow posterity:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Canvas Background through CSS</title>
  <style type="text/css" media="screen">
    canvas, img { display:block; margin:1em auto; border:1px solid black; }
    canvas { background:url(lotsalasers.jpg) }
  </style>
</head><body>
<canvas width="800" height="300"></canvas>
<img>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  var can = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
  var ctx = can.getContext('2d');
  ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
  ctx.lineWidth   = 6;
  ctx.lineJoin    = 'round';
  ctx.strokeRect(140,60,40,40);
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
  img.src = can.toDataURL();
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Is there some way for the CSS background to be considered **part of the image**? I was trying to help this [fellow overflowian](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21835070/607874)

Comment: @JoseRuiSantos No, not via CSS. You would need to `drawImage()` to the canvas for it to be part of it.

Comment: Thats what I thought. As you can see in the link, I am dealing with run-time generated content `-moz-element`, so there is no way to "get" this image, I am afraid. Thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 17):

You can give the background image in css :

```
#canvas { background:url(example.jpg) }
```

it will show you canvas back ground image

Answer (score 3):

You can draw the image on the canvas and let the user draw on top of that.

The `drawImage()` function will help you with that, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Comment: This requires the user to record the drawing commands of the user and 'replay' them on a blank canvas to extract the backgroundless results. Far easier to just not draw the background image in the first place so that you can extract the result without issue.

Comment: indeed it would be. i somehow missed the last sentence of his question or did he add it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin, but for printing purpose i have added some code like
`<button onclick="window.print();">Print</button>` and for saving image `<button onclick="savePhoto();">Save Picture</button>`

```
     function savePhoto() {
     var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
     var img    = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
     window.location = img;}
```

checkout this plugin
http://www.williammalone.com/articles/create-html5-canvas-javascript-drawing-app