# Drawing an image to a <canvas>

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I was trying to draw an image (png-file) to a  to act as a background-image and I do not know why the js i have thus far is not working.

Here's what I have:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('hplogo-z');
var cnvs = canvas.getContext('2d');
background = new Image();
background.onload = function(){
  cnvs.drawImage(background, x, y);
}
background.src = 'bg.png';
```

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you define `x` any `y` anywhere?

Comment: I assume your browser is showing you an error, likely that "x is not defined". Open your error console and look.

Comment: @Phrogz: i forgot to define x & y, but i tried replacing it with 0, 0 and the image still doesn't show.

Comment: @Jcubed : I forgot to define them, but when i replaced x and y with numbers, the image still doesn't appear.

Comment: @theirf Are there errors in your error console? Can you make a simple pared-down test case at http://jsfiddle.net reproducing your problem? What OS/browser/version are you using? Are you certain that the relative path to that image is correct? Are you sure that the image can actually be loaded?

Comment: Finally: are you sure that you need to draw the image to the canvas, instead of just [setting a CSS background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241365/how-to-set-the-background-image-of-a-html-5-canvas-to-png-image)?

Comment: It's a long shot, but are you setting `background` to another value after this code snippet?

Comment: @apsillers : no, i don't believe so.

Comment: @Phrogz : Well, I wanted to try drawing an image first before I tried the CSS solution. [Here is the JS fiddle] (http://jsfiddle.net/jaxBc/) Same issue, just a blank canvas with no image is drawn.

Comment: @theirf There's a syntax error with your fiddle.  I've [fixed it](http://jsfiddle.net/jaxBc/1/) and it works fine(you had an extra http://).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was [unable to reproduce your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/vD73w/1/), so the only things I can guess are that your path is wrong or there is something wrong with your image.

I would recommend you attempt to replace your current path with something from [placehold.it](http://www.placehold.it), or use a different image in a different location in order to see if your image/path is indeed the problem.