# How to set canvas on top of image in html

Tags: html, canvas

Say I have a index.html with a canvas in it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;background: #f2f6f8;">

<div style="display:inline-block;width:auto; margin: 0 auto; background: black; position:relative; border:5px solid black; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 5px 50px #333">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="320" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and the canvas is showing ok this way ~~~

Now I want to put a image as background behind the canvas and I tried to add a img tag in the body:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body style="text-align: center;background: #f2f6f8;">
<img src="xxx.png" alt="" />
<div style="display:inline-block;width:auto; margin: 0 auto; background: black; position:relative; border:5px solid black; border-radius: 10px; box-shadow: 0 5px 50px #333">
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="320" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

but then the canvas appeared to show after the image not on top of it ...

I really know nothing about html I think it should not be that hard to get this done, hope someone can give a hand here, thanks :)

Comment: `<img>` is _not_ a _background_ image. So either position your canvas element on top of it – or use a _real_ background image for your canvas element or its container.

Comment: Check the answer how you can load image in canvas

Comment: how do you expect to see the image when the background of the div containing the canvas is black

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

But the thing is, I can not edit the js files that containg the code in the gameCanvas.

The thing want is like embed the canvas (say a html5 game) in a static html page and the page has a backgroud image (say large than the canvas).

Kinda like the facebook game, a big background and a canvas on it…

Is this possible?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KNxgC/4/)**

You just need to use [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index). I put the image and the canvas element in a container, and position them so the canvas will always be over the image.

Also another note, you shouldn't size your canvas using CSS, you should always do it via the properties directly. In my fiddle I did it via JS.

### Markup

```
<div id="container">
    <img class='img' src="http://lorempixel.com/320/480/" alt="" />
    <canvas id="gameCanvas" width="320" height="480"></canvas>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
body{text-align: center;background: #f2f6f8;}
.img{position:absolute;z-index:1;}

#container{
    display:inline-block;
    width:320px; 
    height:480px;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    background: black; 
    position:relative; 
    border:5px solid black; 
    border-radius: 10px; 
    box-shadow: 0 5px 50px #333}

#gameCanvas{
    position:relative;
    z-index:20;
}
```

Comment: That's cool man!!!

Now the image is under the canvas right now ~~~

The only problem is that I want the canvas to be horizontally centered 
but image to fill the whole bg (it should not be centered) ~~~

I think I shoud edit the css some how ~

Comment: Add following line to #container: box-sizing: content-box; Thereby you make the container big enough that the image and canvas fit perfectly.

Comment: looks like demo is gone

Answer (score 2):

you can draw image in canvas like this , rather than putting `canvas` on image

```
var topMap = new Image();
topMap.src = "myiamge.jpeg";

function drawMap() {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    context.drawImage(topMap, 0, 0);
}

function init() {
    drawMap();
}

topMap.onload = function() {
  init();
}
```

Comment: Not a fan of this since it will cause an uneeded performance hit if hes making anything with animations. He will have to redraw the background each time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer :)

But the thing is, I can not edit the js files that containg the code in the gameCanvas.

The thing want is like embed the canvas (say a html5 game) in a static html page and the page has a backgroud image (say large than the canvas).

Kinda like the facebook game, a big background and a canvas on it…

Is this possible?

Comment: @Loktar - thank i m not getting purpose of putting canvas over image..its better to put image in the div with border...

Answer (score 2):

You can set a background image for the canvas with `background-image: url('xxx.png');` but the background won't be displayed if the user presses `View image` in the browser.

```
<canvas style="background-image: url('xxx.png');"id="gameCanvas" width="320" height="480"></canvas>
```

Or use JavaScript like **Pranay Rana** said (it's better if you have other levels or if you have to change the background later) :)