# canvas drawImage of a div

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I am trying to draw an image on to a canvas. My source is a div that has a collection of text and images. Is this possible to do? I have tried to put some code together but it failed as the canvas is empty.

**Div**

```
<div id="puzzle">
Some text
<img src="sky" />
text text
<img src="sun.png />
</div>
```

**code**

```
<canvas id="mycanvas" width="300" height="150"></canvas>
var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
var ctx = ccanvas.getContext("2d");
var img = document.getElementById("puzzle");
img.onload = function(){
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,40,40);
}
```

Comment: @Alex W this is being used in a chrome extension so i am using javascript files

Comment: `img = document.getElementById("puzzle");` "puzzle" is a `<div>` element, not image. I think this'll help you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
ccanvas.getContext("2d");
```

to

```
canvas.getContext("2d");
```

Otherwise, this seems to be what you're looking for: [Can you take a "screenshot" of the page using Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4340056/can-you-take-a-screenshot-of-the-page-using-canvas)

More specifically: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

Answer (score 0):

write `id=puzzle` inside img tag

Comment: That would make two elements with the `id` of `puzzle`. [`id`s are restricted to one element](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/127180).