# how to capture the screen shot of the web page in html

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to take a screen shot of a web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701798/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-web-page)
>   [How to take screen shot of a div with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887183/how-to-take-screen-shot-of-a-div-with-javascript)

I have a web page i want that when i click capture button then it should capture the screen of the web page and save it in root folder or email it to the given email. is it possible in html5 and java script to do or not

Comment: @Quentin given link is different and not working for me