# Extension to automate screenshots using a carousel

Tags: google-chrome-extension, screenshot, carousel, bookmarklet

Despite multiple searches I am asking as most responses do seem quite old now.

Essentially, I want to take screenshots of a single webpage with a five slot carousel. I want to screengrab each carousel and save automatically in a folder defined by time/date.

I need the software to render and save each page, move the carousel on and repeat. The business I work for needs to do this manually several times a day and I can't help but think there is a quicker way.

I know that JS is very unlikely so a bookmarklet unlikely. However as this will be entirely client-side, does anyone know the best route to take with an extension at all?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand you question correctly but I'm going to to answer anyway

- There is [experimental Chrome API](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture.html) to capture visible page
- There is a lot of capture extensions in the WebStore, they used canvas to capture current page if I recall correctly, but I checked this long time ago. However you could check their code. I'm not sure if you asked about extension only code or about client code as well but I suspect such approach would work for client scripts as well

Hope this helps. Drop me the message if you need help with such extension development

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andreyl. Essentially I'm looking to create an extension that will allow me to grab the screen and save to a location determined by time/date and also named by how far through the macro it has run, then click the next tab in a JS slider on the page and repeat. This will run until the slider has run through 5 tabs. I was unaware that you could see the code from an extension? Perhaps I'm showing my naivety as I haven't worked with Google extensions before as anything I wanted to code in browser was normally achievable through bookmarklets. Is this quite a simple process?

Comment: You could examine code for any extension, each crx is just zip and only java script can be used by the extension. Some extensions minify their scrips and some even obfuscate them but you can check code of other similar extension. Anyway there are some possible answers regarding screenshots: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13970831/how-to-capture-the-screen-shot-of-the-web-page-in-html