# How to take screen shot of the web page email that page in web app

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am making an html5 web app i want that i must  on button click it capture the screen shot of the screen and email that screenshot to given email address.
Is it possible or not

I have studied this but it is not working for me

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/03/screenshot-in-javascript/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to take a screen shot of a web page?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/701798/how-to-take-a-screen-shot-of-a-web-page) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Answer (score 1):

May be you can have a look at this [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/). But It has its limitations.

Comment: http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/09/03/screenshot-in-javascript/ i have tried this but it is not working you can also see this