# Could you please give me the function of taking print screen and convert in to jpg in javascript or flash

Tags: function, printing, screen

Could you please give me the function of taking print screen and convert in to jpg in javascript or flash

Comment: What language and OS? Please be more specific

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Answer (score 2):

For security reasons, these functions are not available to a web browser and consequently not to any code which runs inside of it.

Otherwise, crackers could easily observe what the user is typing on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it would be possible in either of these as then it would be a big security risk. And what would you do with the JPG, considering that you can't write to a file from either of those either?