# image dump from print screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

How would you dump an image captured using the print sreen key into a `div` tag?

Comment: Ctrl+PrtScn. Run paint.exe. Ctrl+V. Save. Upload file to web server. insert a [div] [img src="path_to_screenshot"] [div]. DONE!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried creating a screen shot using print screen and inserting it to a rich HTML field in Firefox. It pastes an IMG tag with a link to a local temporary file (moz-screenshot.png). 
So in the local context (your own computer), it seems possible, but you are going to have a very hard time getting that local file to your server. Maybe with a tweaked Flash upload component.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Best way to do something like this is using a Java applet or ActiveX component.

`clipboardData` is available on IE, but doesn't support access to images. It is not supported by default in Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't.

Now, that said, if you are using Javascript inside of an HTA file, you should read this thread: [Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is good to know about and keep in mind. What a nice feature for any support system, for example. +1