# JavaScript code to take a screenshot of a website without using ActiveX

Tags: javascript, screenshot

I have a JavaScript application that an user interacts with. I need to save the appearance of the interface at the current time, crop out the part that I need (or only shot the part that I need by specifying the div), and send it back to the server.

Clearly any external services would not be able to do this, I need a JavaScript (or [Flash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash)) script that can save the screen appearance. Is this possible?

Also, as the comment below says, I cannot use ActiveX.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Comment: The answer there is about activex, which is not an acceptable solution for me.

Comment: If you cant do active x then you should put that in your question, I'll do so.

Answer (score 9):

Google is doing this in Google+ and a talented developer reverse engineered it and produced http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ .  To work in IE you'll need a canvas support library such as http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I think using JavaScript, you won't be able to due to the security restrictions. Flash, possibly.

Comment: Flash can take Bitmap Snapshots within the Flash Player, but not of HTML content.

Answer (score -2):

It's impossible in pure JavaScript, without using ActiveX.

Comment: +1 for explaining what he'd need.  An active x control could do this, javascript would interface with it.

Comment: It's possible. Go to a youtube video. Click "Report a Bug" all the way down at the bottom of the screen. Canvas seems to be the trick.

Comment: It seems that they are using: JPEG encoder ported to JavaScript and optimized by Andreas Ritter, www.bytestrom.eu, 11/2009
Basic GUI blocking jpeg encoder among other things.

Comment: you may be right - One of the iframes it generates contains a copy of the HTML at the time you clicked the report a bug link. It seems that the HTML is then rendered server side as an image on top of which they overlay the areas highlighted by you when you submitted the bug.

Comment: Hi. I got about same poblem [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-dit-it-no-need). About your comment: why you think YouTube renders report a bug server side? Why then they do  implement JPG encoder in code?

Comment: Here is code of Javascript jpeg encoder http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/source/browse/trunk/third_party/closure/goog/jpeg_encoder/jpeg_encoder_basic.js?r=440

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible using JavaScript (nor Flash). It depends on your constraints, and there are some workarounds.

1. You can take advantage of browser extensions (such as a Firefox add-on), but I guess it does not fit your requierments.
2. The best option I can think of is to construct the [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) tree on the client side, and then post it to remote server.

On the server side nothing really holds you from doing generally anything. Using [WebKit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) or even launching Internet Explorer or Firefox, you can create the snapshot server-side.
It's far from elegant, but possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots