# Is it possible to save a div as an image in asp.net-mvc and leverage it on the server side?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, image, screenshot

I have an asp.net-mvc website and I am using [this jquery plugin to show this treemap](http://philogb.github.io/jit/static/v20/Jit/Examples/Treemap/example1.html).  It works great but recently someone asked for the ability to export this treemap view as an image and I don't think that is possible but wanted to raise this up here for any ideas. My only solution is taking my screen capture tool and taking a snapshot.  I see some jquery plugins like html2canvas that can do stuff client side but not sure how I could leverage that server side.

Is there any programmatic way to take this treemap view and save it as an image?

Answer (score 0):

So basically I assume that the screenshot has to be taken on client side and it has to be either done using javascript/flash.

You will get more details on these links to similar questions in SO which might be helpful and might be of your interest!

[Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript) and [How to take screenshot of div from a webpage using C# and ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4840811/how-to-take-screenshot-of-div-from-a-webpage-using-c-sharp-and-asp-net)