# Capture the Window Screen for few minutes using ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

"Through out the question I just talk only on the client side using asp.net"

My requirement is to "Capture the window screen for few minutes and store it as video of any format."

For example if I want to capture the screen of the window and store in some jpeg or gif format, I can use the system.windows.forms library and can achieve as below code

```
public void StartCapturing(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height);
        System.Drawing.Graphics graphics = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(bitmap as System.Drawing.Image);
        graphics.CopyFromScreen(25, 25, 25, 25, bitmap.Size);
        bitmap.Save(@"D:\Raghu\MyScreenshots\myscreenshot3.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
}
```

So my question is that is there any library that I can include so that it can satisfy my need by adding some code as simple as possible. I have seen some tools like snagit etc., but I could n't get clarity regarding that. Any clarifications are appreciated...

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by 'only on the client side using asp.net' - Do you want to run a separate program which captures your website's output, or do you want your website to capture its own output ?

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try looking at Selenium to capture snapshots of your website see [Take a screenshot with Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: I already mentioned that I got the method and the desired output, for just snapshot or screen shot , so now I would like to go a step further and get the window screen recording for few minutes and store it in a video format file