# Export Highcharts and Html Table

Tags: jquery, html, highcharts

I have a requirement where to export HTML table and high chart as a image.

Currently there is a toggle button , on click of which the system will show either the legend or HTML table (in the place of the legend) and on click of the toggle button , the chart should be printed / exported either with the legend or HTML table (which ever is toggled).

Printing is achieved using jquery.printElement plugin. I am trying to do so for exporting as well. Tried using HTML5 Canvas, but it doesnt works. Can any one suggest on what will be the best approach to achieve this?

```
<div id="block_container">
    <div id="container"></div> <!-- which will rendered with highchart -->
    <div id="datatableContent" style="display:none">
        <table border='1'> 
            <tr><td>month</td><td>values</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Jan</td><td>Assinged Time</td></tr>
            <tr><td>Feb</td><td>Applied Time</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

and in Script

```
$('#print1').click(function() {
    $('#block_container').printElement();
});
```

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee

Comment: See http://www.highcharts.com/docs/frequently-asked-questions#add-data-table