# Take screen shot of url with PHP using specific website width?

Tags: php, jquery

I see there is a lot of info on how to save a websites to an image with PHP, however I cannot find any information on how to take a screen shot of a website using a specific width.

I want to take a screen shot using PHP of my websites in different widths, so I have screen shots of the design in different responsive modes (Desktop, Tablets, Phones).

Does anyone know how to save a url to an image with a specific width set, using PHP? (or with help from Javascript/jQuery for all I care)

Comment: Instead of PHP you need more of Javascript  to do that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee

Comment: From what i read, the Javascript solution only lets me download the file client side and does not save it on to the server, I need the file on my server.

Comment: What is with the down votes on stackover flow these weeks. 3 seconds into the topic open and 3 automated down votes? No one can read that in 3 seconds what I wrote. And what is wrong with my question?

Comment: This might be helpful: http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since every one is so smart on Stackoverflow and just down votes for a question that has not been answered on Stackoverflow ever! Here is my solution to a perfectly valid question.

PHP cannot set the width of the website when taking a screen shot (using cUrl or copy), however using iFrame, you can create an iFrame, set the width of the iFrame and take a screen shot of that page.