# Automatically render HTML to Image

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, render

I know it's possible to render HTML code as an image. However, I would like to make the image update every 30 seconds, 1 minute etc. etc.

I am attempting to display the price of various assets on sites that don't allow JavaScript. So, in order to do this, I will host the script on my own domain that should then render an image and most importantly, update that image as often as possible, while still keeping it in the same location on my site.

Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Use cavans: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp

Comment: But where is the .png image saved on my domain? It needs to be in the same place every time it updates. It should update automatically, without anyone visiting the page, as the image is going to be [IMG]'d on other sites, no traffic will be direct

Answer (score 0):

if the website is php,asp,etc that's allow to make changes to a folder of images and inside a database text,prices,...etc and you can't want to use javascript for any reasons.. eg:the parser 's method you choose OR eg: in apk i put my browser that render only html ,not javascript, then you can use in your html output   this will refresh your page after 30 secconds so if in this time you modify the image at the same location =same name other content of the same image you will have a "new" page with modifies done.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with that. I want to display the image on a site that I don't own, so I will use the normal [IMG] tag and then link to mydomain.com/image.png.

This image should be a screenshot of a script widget, and should update every 1 minute.

Comment: there are many chances this will not work but seeing the html context and other things is in that website were you can put limited content i can give you the right answer! anyway there is another trick were you can upload an image to make it "refresh" is a animated gif with frames with the pause 60 secconds how you ask

Comment: For example, I want to embed: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://files.coinmarketcap.com/static/widget/currency.js"></script>
<div class="coinmarketcap-currency-widget" data-currency="bitcoin" data-base="USD" ></div> on a forum that only allows images.

Comment: you can't without special permissions cause anyone now had parsers for javascript posted to be commented as text or replaced by blank , cause me and the rest of the world we treat as code injections and somehow xss attack ...so isn't a good ideea to try to upload that kind of content in a website cause they treath you as a hacker

Comment: I don't think you understand. I will upload the above code to my website. Say mydomain.com/btc the script I want then screenshots that to mydomain.com/btc.png and then I can share mydomain.com/btc.png on any website I want

Comment: there is a partial answer to a conversion html and javascript to a image here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34783874/html-code-to-png-image