# Is it possible to take a screenshot on a webpage in JS after X second from the last action?

Tags: javascript, html, webpage-screenshot, takesscreenshot

I have a web page and I want to take a screenshot when I don't use the page after X seconds, that is, when a certain time is reached after the last action
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621907/how-to-screenshot-website-in-javascript-client-side-how-google-did-it-no-nee)s, a simple google search will help you faster than asking a question.

Additionally,

```
let timeout
let seconds = 2
function screenshot(){
   clearTimeout(timeout)
   timeout = setTimeout(function(){takescreenshot()},seconds*1000)
}
document.body.addEventListener("mousemove",function(){screenshot()});
document.body.addEventListener("click",function(){screenshot()})
```