# Javascript to input searches on multiple websites and take a screenshot

Tags: javascript, search, screenshot

I am trying to automate the querying of names on 2 different websites. For each website I have to enter in the same name and take a screenshot of the results.I don't know how to approach this project. Is it possible to automate this with a javascript? Thank you for any input.

Website links are below:

[1] http://exclusions.oig.hhs.gov/search.aspx

[2] http://www.health.ny.gov/professionals/doctors/conduct/license_lookup.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript to take a screenshot of a website without using ActiveX](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046812/javascript-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-without-using-activex)

Comment: Yes, but now with JavaScript. You need to do this on a server.

Comment: I added the java tag because I had figured it may not be possible to be done in javascript. Which Diodeus has confirmed. How would I accomplish this on a server?

Comment: There are a lot of jaw-dropping javascript libraries nowadays. Check out Jesse's answer. Or http://hertzen.com/experiments/jsfeedback/ if canvas is an option. And if you want to do it on the server-side, you should describe your framework.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to accomplish this with [PhantomJS](http://www.phantomjs.org/) relatively easily. Check out the examples page - you'll probably want to use [code evaluation](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Code_Evaluation) to fill out and submit your forms, after which you can [render](http://code.google.com/p/phantomjs/wiki/QuickStart#Rendering) the page to an image file.

Answer (score 0):

You actually do this is one step: send a POST requests to the information you need. For the first example, you would send these POST data:

```
__VIEWSTATE=dDwtNzQ5MzEyMDI3Ozs%2BHWC8LXZfQQTCTJWtmudNLStjn%2Fk%3D&txtLastName1=test&txtFirstName1=&txtBusinessName1=&txtLastName2=&txtFirstName2=&txtBusinessName2=&txtLastName3=&txtFirstName3=&txtBusinessName3=&txtLastName4=&txtFirstName4=&txtBusinessName4=&txtLastName5=&txtFirstName5=&txtBusinessName5=&cmdSubmit=Search
```

So you can use PhantomJS, as suggested, with a POST request and take a screenshot. Or you can use a web service to create the screenshots. Unfortunately, very few allow POST requests with custom POST data. [Browshot](http://browshot.com/) (see [API](https://browshot.com/api/documentation)) lets you send POST data and use a custom Referer. So your screenshot requests would include (after you encode the POST data):

```
url=http://exclusions.oig.hhs.gov/search.aspx&referer=http://exclusions.oig.hhs.gov/search.aspx&post_data=__VIEWSTATE%3DdDwtNzQ5MzEyMDI3Ozs%252BHWC8LXZfQQTCTJWtmudNLStjn%252Fk%253D%26txtLastName1%3Dtest%26txtFirstName1%3D%26txtBusinessName1%3D%26txtLastName2%3D%26txtFirstName2%3D%26txtBusinessName2%3D%26txtLastName3%3D%26txtFirstName3%3D%26txtBusinessName3%3D%26txtLastName4%3D%26txtFirstName4%3D%26txtBusinessName4%3D%26txtLastName5%3D%26txtFirstName5%3D%26txtBusinessName5%3D%26cmdSubmit%3DSearch
```

I have tested it, and do get a screenshot of the results, like if I filled out the form and submitted it.

Comment: When I use the url "http://exclusions.oig.hhs.gov/search.aspx&referer=http://exclusions.oig.hhs.gov/search.aspx&post_data=__VIEWSTATE%3DdDwtNzQ5MzEyMDI3Ozs%252BHWC8LXZfQQTCTJWtmudNLStjn%252Fk%253D%26txtLastName1%3Dtest%26txtFirstName1%3D%26txtBusinessName1%3D%26txtLastName2%3D%26txtFirstName2%3D%26txtBusinessName2%3D%26txtLastName3%3D%26txtFirstName3%3D%26txtBusinessName3%3D%26txtLastName4%3D%26txtFirstName4%3D%26txtBusinessName4%3D%26txtLastName5%3D%26txtFirstName5%3D%26txtBusinessName5%3D%26cmdSubmit%3DSearch" I am getting a Bad Request (Invalid URL) error. Any ideas?