# Capture screenshot of an iframe

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe, screenshot

I am trying to make a small piece of code that will let the user type a web adress in an input/popup dialog and then show it in an iframe.However what happens if that adress has animations in it?For instance google ads or banners that will be constantly animated?Would it be possible somehow to stop the animations show that there is something like a plain picture of the site or capture a screenshot of it and save it for display later?

Comment: You could stick a `while(1)` in it, but that would kind of freeze up everything, not just the animations :p

Comment: why stop the animations? they'll load and animate, what's your question?

Comment: We're not sure what you're trying to achieve - the address doesn't have animations in it, the page that it points to does; just like people don't live in the address, but in the home at that address. Why do you need this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use java `java.awt.Robot` class do the work, for more informations, take a look at the methods that it offer here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html
Otherwise, there's this post that can help you: [JavaScript code to take a screenshot of a website without using ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046812/javascript-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-without-using-activex)
Hope that helps