# screenshot of a webpage using asp.net without any exe

Tags: c#, asp.net, screenshot, webpage-screenshot

Is tat possible to get a screenshot of a webpage using asp.net without any exe?

If so please provide me some details or links.

Note: Since my hosting provider doesn't allow exe's to run, I can't use exes

Thanks in Advance

Comment: take a look at here http://ramanisandeep.net/2009/12/05/capture-web-page-as-image-using-asp-net/  and  http://www.websitesscreenshot.com/

Comment: Let me look into this, I've done it for a winform app, pretty sure I didn't use an .exe, setting this comment as a reminder to look at code tonight at home.

Comment: Ahhh yes, now I recall. My idea won't work, as you're using ASP.NET? I was thinking of using System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser.DrawToBitmap() but that requires a webbrowser control, nothing like that in ASP.NET. Sorry.... in winforms, it's actually really simple.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like Awesomium:

http://awesomium.com/

It's a fork of the Chromium browser, and has managed wrappers.  It's designed for capturing screen shots and doing other "browser" things without the context of a window.

Answer (score 1):

find some threads in stackoverflow, they maybe be helpful.
[Javascript to take a screenshot of a website without using ActiveX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046812/javascript-to-take-a-screenshot-of-a-website-without-using-activex)
[Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)