# How to take a screenshot of the user's screen when the user places an order?

Tags: asp-classic, screenshot

I don't mind if it is a print screen or export proccess of the page to jpg or even to pdf... how can it be done?

Comment: what is that? can you explain that?

Comment: i'm not talking about printing the page for the user... i need to save a copy of what the user had on his screen when he clicked the order button

Comment: ASP is a *server-side* technology, you know that?

Comment: Yes i do... so do asp.net and still there are website having a "screenshot" of the reservation

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you *literally* want to save a screenshot of the user's desktop, this can't be done with server-side technology like ASP, since the user's desktop is not on your server (obviously).

There might be a JavaScript solution (I couldn't find one), or you can use ActiveX ([Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)), which might not be a good idea if this is a public ordering system, since many users won't be able to use (or will turn off) ActiveX--I know I'm personally alarmed to see ActiveX notification these days, and that would likely change my mind about placing an order in the first place.

However, I would very much question the need to take a literal screenshot, instead of just recording the relevant data in a database or log somewhere (and then you could simulate the user's screen).