# How does gmail report a bug works - technically?

Tags: javascript, html

How does gmail report a bug works - technically?

By this I mean.. what HTML, JS techniques they may have used to get screenshot plugin kind of interface.. and technique.

Comment: is this you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Comment: This may help in understanding the issue...http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2010/08/gmails-new-bug-reporting-interface.html

Comment: @Ramesh, Yes something like this.. but in case of Gmail, no plugin is being used.. and it works on all browsers.. I wonder how.

Comment: may be they used Flash !