# Screenshot of the content of a textbox

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, html, image-processing

is it possible to take a screenshot of what a textbox holds when the user presses the sumbit button for example?

EDIT: this is an aspx webpage

Comment: The use of `html` in the tag implies that this is a webpage and you are using asp.net - is that the case? Can you confirm this is not a winforms/wpf application using a browser control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no it is not possible to do this in a consistent, cross browser fashion (that I am aware of).  If your textbox was implemented inside of a flash movie, it would be possible to take a 'screenshot' of what the flash movie was displaying when a button was pressed ([discussion on this subject available here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=187144)).  But otherwise, you are going to have to do this processing on the server.

You could simulate this process by having the server render a copy of the page itself (feeding it the data the user entered) and then doing what you wanted with it from there.  There are free and paid for solutions to assist you in taking a screenshot of a website ([browse options available here](http://www.google.com/search?q=asp.net+website+screenshot)).

Answer (score 0):

On the client side I think you're stuck with the limitations of javascript, which might not be possible. Here is another question that is very similar to yours:

[Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

In the general sense, no, you can't. However if you have a constrained environment (e.g. kiosk, intranet), you can create a browser plug-in which can essentially do anything, including snapping a screenshot and sending it to the server.

If you have lots of control over the environment, you can create your own web browser which can take screenshots. In fact, I've done this with C#. I just wrote an app that hosts a browser control and sends screenshots to the server on certain key presses or at a user-defined interval.