# Is it possible to fetch a rectangular section of a web-page as an image via JavaScript?

Tags: html, canvas, webkit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

I'm developing an interactive HTML page and am looking for a way to capture an arbitrary portion of this page into a dataURI (Base64 encoded PNG).

I know its possible to get this for a canvas element but do modern browsers provide any way to do this for an arbitrary section of the page?

Comment: not even google can do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots :)

Answer (score 2):

**Not without sending it off server-side.**

You could send an AJAX request to your server with some parameters (url, anchor, offset dimensions etc) and return a base64 string of the captured image.

Here's an [example](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2008/07/c-generate-webpage-thumbmail-screenshot-image.aspx) of capturing an image server-side using C#, there should be examples in other languages as well.