# javascript screenshot in .net without server side code

Tags: c#, javascript, .net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)
>   [taking screenshots of an application using WSH Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370673/taking-screenshots-of-an-application-using-wsh-script)

I would like to get a screenshot of a website with a javascript in my c# solution. I don't want to include any server side code, just client side code. 
Can someone please help me with that, with some example, is that doable or no? 
Thanks in advance, Laziale

Answer (score 1):

There's a pretty new JavaScript library that I've heard a lot about but haven't tried yet that does what I think you're looking for.  It's called [html2canvas](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas) and is available on github.  Here's the description.

> This script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Html2Cavnas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/), it's the method that Google Plus uses in their feedback mechanism, it's not a true screenshot but pretty much as close as you can get with native client side code.