# How to take page screen shot of a visitor?

Tags: screenshot

How to take page screen shot of a visitor? Like Gmail bug filler. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bi2QT.png

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is one way: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com ― I haven't actually tried it out so I don't know if it works.

Answer (score 2):

If you like a drop-in solution, give Usersnap a try ( http://usersnap.com ) - installing is as simple as adding google analytics and the screenshots are accurate.