# screenshot on javascript and java

Tags: java, javascript, ajax

I am using google visualization api for my java based website. I am planning to capture the screen shots of my clients wedpage having images generated by Google Visualization API,and i want to prepare Ppt using that screenshots.

is there any way to save these visualizations on my server so that i use them directly on my application to generate pptfile?

Suggestions please?

Thanks,
priyanka

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript/4012915#4012915

Comment: If your website is only a java applet, you shouldn't need JavaScript.