# How to take a screenshot of specific area on page using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

I am stuck in a problem.i ve got a case where i am manipulating a image and adding overlay divs after some processing. after all the processing done i wan to save that specific area where the image lies coz image has overlay divs. so is there a to take screen shot of specific area of the page and then save it as image.

Thanks

Comment: Sup bruv if you wantz uz to write da code for u, u might wanna offa uz a bounty innit. cheers.

Comment: You may have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Comment: @peduarte did i ask you to write code for me. i only asked for some guidance.. not for particular code

Comment: @Jav Diodeus is right. You can't do this without a plugin.

Comment: @NullUserException yes probably..

Comment: GitHub library html2Canvas https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas **GitHub 25K stars** as  of today Apr 2020 Azure pipeles : Succeeded , Downloads 1.3M/mo   |  quote : " _JavaScript HTML renderer The script allows you to take "screenshots" of webpages or parts of it, directly on the users browser. The screenshot is based on the DOM and as such may not be 100% accurate to the real representation as it does not make an actual screenshot, but builds the screenshot based on the information available on the page._

Answer (score 1):

You can't. You need to use a browser plug-in.

Comment: i know its possible through plugin.i have come across through html canvas.where it is possible to take screenshot of the canvas.but its not really helpful at all..