# How can i create an SVG file (XML) using the array of SVG shapes my method returns?

Tags: javascript, html, json, svg

I have a method:

```
line.prototype.exportSVG = function() {
    return this.getrdlineElements().map(function(element) {
        return element.exportSVG();
    });
}
```

this method returns an array of SVG shapes example `[rect, path, ellipse]`

Instead of returning the elements in an array i want to return these as a string (xml) and in another function (importSVG) i will use this string data to create an svg image file.

how can i do this?

thanks in advance :)

Comment: What are `[rect, path, ellipse]`?  SVGElements? Here you'l find out how to create and download a standalone svg inside this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477972/javascript-save-svg-element-to-file-on-disk/38481556#38481556), just read the exportSVG function, you can remove the parseStyles part and don't need to create a clone.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] so we can properly see what you are trying to do.