# How to take screenshot of a webpage after running javascript

Tags: javascript, html, latex, screenshot

I have a webpage which renders LaTeX formula using javascript. I wish to take a screenshot of it programmatically after running the scripts. Is this possible?

Comment: May be this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Comment: @NAVEED Can it be done in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [webkit2png](http://www.paulhammond.org/webkit2png/) and apply the `delay` option to wait for JS to finish rendering the formulae before taking the screenshot.

Answer (score 4):

There is a cross platform, HTML5 solution, works with latest browsers only http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/

> The script should work fine on the following browsers:
>
> Firefox 3.5+
>
> Google Chrome Newer versions of Opera
>
> IE9 (Older versions compatible with the use of flashcanvas)

**Demo:** http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/screenshots.html

Comment: Seems that it cannot render javascript as I want

Comment: Give it a try I think it might be possible, I am afraid you may not find any better solution.

Comment: I want to, for example, take a screenshot of the formula on the index page of mathjax: http://www.mathjax.org/ and it failed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a headless browser like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html) to render LaTeX / MathJax.

Related [How can I force PhantomJS to wait until MathJax is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40669585/how-can-i-force-phantomjs-to-wait-until-mathjax-is-finished)