# How can I force PhantomJS to wait until MathJax is finished?

Tags: javascript, html, callback, phantomjs, mathjax

I'm trying to *pre-render* a MathJax html file using PhantomJS. For example, suppose in `math.html` I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="MathJax/MathJax.js"></script>
    <script src="ConfigMathJax.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="math">\(e = m c^2\)</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

My (broken) render script currently looks like:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
page.open(system.args[1], function () {
    page.evaluate(function(){
      var flag = false;
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(function(){
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
      });
    });
});
```

I've *attempted* to write the page to standard out and exit [after](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/Event-when-typesetting-is-done%3F-Rescaling-after-rendering...) the MathJax render command is called from the queue. But it seems I'm in the "page"'s context rather than the top-level Phantom context. The variable `page` can't be found: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: page`.

It I hack in a `setTimeout` instead of using the flag:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();                                                  
var system = require('system');                                                          
var fs = require('fs');                                                                  
page.open(system.args[1], function () {                                                  
    page.evaluate(function(){                                                            
      MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);                                        
    });                                                                                  
    setTimeout(function(){                                                               
      console.log(page.content);                                                         
      phantom.exit();                                                                    
    },10000);                                                                            
});
```

then I get the desired output, but of course the wait time `10000`ms will depend on the content.

How can I let PhantomJS know that MathJax is done rendering?

Is this a sandbox issue?

Comment: JavaScript is single-threaded. You can't stop an infinite loop with an asynchronous event, because the event is blocked until the thread is available.

Comment: Ah, I read the answers on this too quickly: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22125915/148668

Comment: Exactly, so rather than setting a flag in the callback, put the statements you want to execute in the callback.

Comment: I agree now that the `while(flag==false)` is wrong, but the phantomjs sandbox seems to be making it hard to call `console.log(page.content);                                                        phantom.exit(); ` in the write _context_ (if that's the right term here).

Comment: Not a direct answer but we created [mathjax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-node) to make server-side processing easy.

Comment: @Peter Krautzberger, That totally solved what I was trying to do. This question is a bit moot now (though I'm still curious why it fails).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');                                                          
var fs = require('fs');
page.open(system.args[1], function () {
  page.evaluate(function () {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(
      ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub],
      function () {
        console.log(page.content);
        phantom.exit();
      }
    );
  });
});
```

This will queue the console output and `phantom.exit()` calls to occur immediately after the typesetting occurs.  I haven't tested the code, but this is the way to synchronize something with MathJax's process.

---

**UPDATE**

Try this:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');                                                          
var fs = require('fs');
page.open(system.args[1], function () {
  page.onAlert = function (msg) {
    if (msg === "MathJax Done") {
      console.log(page.content);
    } else if (msg === "MathJax Timeout") {
      console.log("Timed out waiting for MathJax");
    } else {console.log(msg)}
    phantom.exit();
  };
  page.evaluate(function () {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(
      ["Typeset",MathJax.Hub],
      [alert,'MathJax Done']
    );
    setTimeout(function () {alert("MathJax Timeout")},10000);  // timeout after 10 seconds
  });
});
```

Comment: Seems like the sandbox is foiling this. I get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: page`.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a new version to try.  You might also look at [code I provided](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/mathjax-users/nQXVaFi4IKQ/AwZ-UrRhiDAJ) years ago for producing an SVG from MathJax via phantom.js (that has since been superseded by mathjax-node, as Peter suggested).  I cribbed the code above from that earlier code example.

Comment: The updated code works. That's quite a workaround, I wouldn't have thought to use alert that way.