# Screenshot image from php

Tags: php, screenshot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)
>   [Website screenshots using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/757675/website-screenshots-using-php)

I need get a screenshot image by php without have to do manually. In this php I would like write a screen parameters to customize my screenshot image.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need something to render the page: [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), for example. For pure PHP, you'll have to use a service like [Browshot](https://browshot.com/api/libraries/php) which offer an API to request screenshots with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a server side language, so making a screen shot off your client machine needs an other technology.

Look at the [GD library of PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-png.php) to invest the possibilities of image and PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you can call a binary from your PHP script you can use WkHTML. It handle both PDF and image conversion pretty well.
I am using it to render fragments (like tables) but it works with a whole page. It can even wait for AJAX loads and other Javascript sturr.
 http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ is the link.