# Create Image/pdf/screenshot of webpage on click of a button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have looked a for a way of allowing a user to click a button that will allow them to save an image or pdf  of the current page.  The page always chnages and relys on user input, based on this , sequences  are returned , colored in different ways.  So any way that will allow the user to take a screenshot and download it or save page as image , via  a button or link.  Can anyone help??

Comment: Look here this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Comment: What are some methods you have tried?

Comment: I believe you could maybe use html2Canvas also, ive heard it mentioned but not sure about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not a just like "add the button", you'll need many lines of code on the `server-side` if you'll decide to do it on your own.

If you really want to add the button only, I'd suggest to use [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com) for this task, it offers hundreds of possibilites, also online PDF generating, sharing by e-mail, support for social network sites, etc etc

Comment: i meant that button would initate the event.

Comment: Yes, I asserted that, anyway maybe it's really easier to use some multipurpose widget, than create all the server-side stuff. Just a suggestion.