# Capture Browser Web Page

Tags: javascript, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

I searched through google and here but I am not able to find exact solution of a JavaScript / mechanism to capture web page image which is rendered in the browser - say I visit site - www.google.com and through JS I should be able to capture / save/ see the web page rendered.

My requirement is to help our QAs with automatic capturing of web page to store values entered in the web page

Comment: If you just need to scrape entered values, you could probably leverage Selenium.

Comment: An image helps / speaks a lot about the web page itself. How can I leverage it via Selenium?

Comment: See SO question [Take a screenshot with Selenium webdriver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3422262/take-a-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver).

Comment: Thanks. But is the same not possible at client / browser side itself? Is Selenium an open source code?