# Save multiple overlapped transparent images to a single image

Tags: javascript, transparency, image

I have multiple overlapped images with transparent background just like layers in photoshop each loaded in "img" tag. I need to change color of some layers and i did it by using javascript, now i want to merge all the images and save them into single image file just like in photshop. Do anyone have any idea on this? Can anyone suggest me any plugin for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript More precisely, I'm referring to this: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ You can take "screenshot" of the element that contains all the layers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest is to have an [HTML canvas](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/) and then

- draw images on it, [setting the alpha](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-context-2d-globalalpha) depending on the transparency you want for each image
- save the canvas as PNG using [toDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement)