# Server-Side get height of website document and return?

Tags: php, server-side

Is it possible to use PHP, or some other server side programming language, to get the height of a website and return it to HTML? The site that I want to get the height from is not on my server and I have no control over it.

I know you can get your server to take screen shots of websites, so maybe you could get the height of the image it returns. Just an idea.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the meaning  of height of website ?

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript

Comment: You'd need something that can basically render the page, e.g. headless firefox.