# How to convert html blob into image using javascript?

Tags: javascript, blob

Trying to create image(screenshot) of a HTML page using javascript. Able to generate the html blob and display the same in new tab as read only HTML page using the below code.

```
var scr = document.documentElement.cloneNode(true);
var blob = new Blob([scr.outerHTML], {type: 'text/html'});
window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(blob));
```

Please anyone could tell me how to save the same as image.

Comment: yes couldn't get anything near

Comment: here is what i found: http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/  http://grabz.it/ http://stackoverflow.com/a/9269601/834424

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at FileSaver.js,

```
var bb = new BlobBuilder();
bb.append((new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(document));
var blob = bb.getBlob("application/xhtml+xml;charset=" + document.characterSet);
saveAs(blob, "document.xhtml");
```

[Some Documentation](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side)

[API](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js)