# Javascript library to take screenshot of web page

Tags: javascript, html, screenshot

This [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript) was asked a long time a ago (4 years ago). I was wondering if there are any new advancements in the library ecosystem.

My use case is quite simple, I have a styled DIV and some elements within - I'd like to create a screenshot of that DIV.

```
Takes this:                                            Into this:
----------------------------                           ------------------------
<div class="potrait">
    <img src="sergio.jpg" />   --> Turns it into -->   sergio.png
    <h1>Sergio tapia</h1>
</div>
```

Is there anything out there that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Is your use case client side?

Comment: What for a server technology?

Comment: I'm using C# and ASP.Net MVC3. I understand it may not be possible to do it 100% client side (in fact I'm 99.9% sure) but I'd be happy with something that packages the info cleanly and send it to my server for processing.

Comment: I don't know of any new technologies. See the lots of related question in the right column, their answer still apply.

Answer (score 3):

You have two possibilities:

1. rerender the div with a lib like [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)
2. Render it on a server

Taking a real screenshot from js is not possible.