# Update Image, capture screengrab and save to disk using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Refresh Image Src content and Stop the refreshing**

Hi, i have a function that refresh the "src" attr every second. , now i want when i click button stop, it will stop the interval, in addtion, to make a button to take the picture and save it to computer, like snapshot.

```
<img src="http://someurl" id="image1" class="g" />
<button id="stop">STOP!</button>
<button id="capture">capture</button>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/vmVTU/) 
you can see here what i wrote and give me directions , thanks.

Comment: this isn't really possible, you can't just force user to download file, even if you did manage that, it wouldn't work in all browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Canvas2Image](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)** plugin might help you.

Using the HTML5 canvas element, you can create all sorts of cool graphics client-side on the fly using Javascript. However, the canvas image cannot (in all browsers) simply be saved to disk as any other image.

Luckily there is a neat function on the the canvas object called toDataURL(). This functions encodes the image data as a base64 encoded PNG file and returns it as a data: URI.

To work in IE you'll need a canvas support library such as http://excanvas.sourceforge.net/

Also check out [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

**Edit:**

Refreshing image is simple:

```
    //Declare array of images
    var images = ['http://www.creativereview.co.uk/images/uploads/2012/10/1_press_image_l_for_the_lol_of_cats_l_maru_0.jpg',
                  'http://blog.naseeb.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/cute-cat.jpg',
                  'http://www.helpinghomelesscats.com/images/cat1.jpg'];

    var loop = 0;

    //This function will refresh image on specified interval 
    function refreshImages() {
        $('#myimage').attr('src', images[loop]);

        loop++;

        if (loop === images.length) {
            loop = 0;
        }
    }

    //Set Refresh time here
    var setInt = self.setInterval(function() {
        refreshImages();
    }, 1000);

    //This button stops the image refreshing
    $('#stop').click(function() {
        setInt = window.clearInterval(setInt);
    });​

    //Add image capture code here
```

[Working DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hDRYX/5/)

Comment: what about stopping refresh?