# How can users draw and save images within a website?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to develop a website that allows users to draw their own pictures on the website with either the mouse or finger, for example a stick figure. I then want to be able to save the image so it can then be printed.  Can anyone help as to what is the best way to go about this.

I have a pretty good understanding of html and css but I do believe this will require something more advanced for me to learn.  Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use HTML5 canvas element to achieve this and it's a pretty complex task in my opinion but feasible.

You need to have excellent understanding of canvas interactions and drawing tools. You can find a very basic drawing application here.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/html5-canvas-painting/

Once user is happy with painting then you can save it to disk. Below is an example to do so:

[Update Image, capture screengrab and save to disk using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13520641/update-image-capture-screengrab-and-save-to-disk-using-javascript/13521213#13521213)

Comment: Thank you so much - link just what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this. You can have a look at [svg-edit](http://code.google.com/p/svg-edit/), for example, which is an online SVG (vector graphics) editor ([demo](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html)).

Or you can use the `canvas` element. See this question: [Online Photoshop via HTML 5's Canvas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825958/online-photoshop-via-html-5s-canvas)

Comment: As the canvas element isn't great in all browsers is it best to use the svg-edit?  Do you know if svg-edit could possibly be integrated into a website with just a few of the functions eg: pencil and eraser and color? thanks for your help

Comment: There is no solution that is great in all browsers; each decision will have its limitations. I haven't tried to integrate svg-edit into anything, I'd just use it as a starting point to find out what you can do.