# Screen capture using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Take a screenshot of a webpage with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

I have got a real problem to export a dynamic google map into a jpg or png image.

A client can draw his own trip with a google map API v3 interface with custom markers and some other stuff.
I want to export his trip on jpg image.

I already tried the statics maps and html2canvas but it doesn't work.

I want to re use the generate image put it in a pdf generate with the fpdf library.

Sorry for my poor english, I'm French and not very good in the Shakespeare's language.

I already thank you if you can help me because it's a very big project I have and I'm lost.

Comment: Maybe this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots

Comment: Depending on what you want to do with it, you _may_ be violating the Google copyright or TOS by saving the map as a PDF or JPG.

Comment: Am i really violating the google licence if I do that ?

Comment: sorry, I didn't explain, it's for a commercial use

Comment: I'm not a legal expert, [but read their TOS... you may be in violation.  Just one quote from Section 8.3: _"...You may be held liable for any unauthorized copying or disclosure of this content. Your use of Tele Atlas map data and certain other Content (including certain business listings Content) is subject to additional restrictions located in the Legal Notices page..."_](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Javascript has no access to the file system, therefore you cannot save a file with it.

2 - Saving images from Google Maps is not allowed. See here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#tos_screenshots

> Use of Google Maps imagery in printed materials **and offline media** is
>   subject to the Permission Guidelines published at:
>
> http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html

you can request permission, but I don't think it's easy to obtain, unless you are a paying  business customer.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I think I will talk about that with my boss to know if he knows these constraints.