# Cross-Domain Screenshot

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a PHP site and there is a cross domain iframe in it.

```
<iframe src="https://sketchfab.com/embed/f72166969def4de1acda21912ef6fe82?autostart=1&amp;transparent=1&amp;controls=0&amp;watermark=0&amp;desc_button=0&amp;stop_button=0" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="480"></iframe>
```

Is there any way that i can allow my users to screenshot it? it is not a static page where user can have some activites in the iframe eg. users can rotate or zoom in the model and screenshot on certain part.

Comment: iframe page work completely but u cant interact via code to iframe.

Comment: true i saw it's cross domain origin issue. just wondering if there is any other ways to do it.

Comment: You may be interested in resizing the iframe, scrolling it if necessary and taking screenshot with javascript. For taking screenshots look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript