# Programmatically trigger mac screenshot using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, macos

Is there a way to trigger the built in Mac screenshot capture for page and area from a webpage? Manually I can trigger on my keyboard the

`Command + shift + 4` or `Command + Shift + 3`

In my web app I have a button with a click event to "capture screen" I just want to attach to this click event to trigger the mac OS screen capture tool.

```
$(".captureScreen").click(function () {
    // Add Trigger here for Mac Screen Shot 
});
```

I can't seem to find any examples using JavaScript, maybe it cannot be accessed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Take a screenshot of a webpage with JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript)

Comment: Not going to vote to close as duplicate, because it is mac specific

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't, and there's a very good reason for that.

Imagine what would happen if this was possible, and somebody wrote a script that does this continuously, and as fast as possible...

A possible alternative is to use a java applett (or activeX control if you're not bound to OSX) to do this.
You could start the applett / control from javascript and wait for its reply from javascript as well.

Note that this is not a perfect solution, as it will not work in mobile browsers or for people who have java turned off, or not installed, etc.
It will also trigger a dialog box prompting the user to accept running the applett.

There are ways around this using HTML5 though, and i suggest looking in the thread Sam P posted.

Comment: was also thinking, but couldn't I just trigger the keyboard presses on the keyboard `Command + shift + 4` to simulate a press which would fire the native screenshot on the Mac?

Comment: No, Javascript is "sandboxed" in so much that it won't allow you to do things outside the browser window.
The reasoning behind this is simple : security.
If you could trigger OS functions from an anonymous web page by firing keypresses, that would be a gaping security hole.

Comment: Besides that, `Command + shift + 4` is not per se always the "take screenshot" combination. you can redefine it manually.

Comment: No problem :) hope you find a viable solution to your problem though.

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it, but this [npm respository](https://www.npmjs.com/package/desktop-screenshot) claims to be able to do it.

However, it looks like it is for use on your local machine only.  Still, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: That package is only relying on a shell script to call the same command you would if you pressed `printScreen` yourself, which after all is just a shortcut to an executable. It wouldn't work from the browser