# Is passing a screen shot from the front end and send it to the back end a reasonable thing to do in Rail?

Tags: ruby, google-maps, ruby-on-rails-4, google-maps-api-3

I'm doing a project that my back end program needs a image generated from google map api. It is the exact same image that is on the users monitor. I'm currently using google map api to generate the picture but since it contains long and multiple parameters, it exceeds the url length limit(more than 3k chars). I can do multiple requests on google map(more than 10) which will return more than 10 images and than combine them into one. But the process of doing this gets very hairy and I was thinking if it is possible to capture a screen shot when the user is viewing the map and pass it to the back end. How does the two ways compare in terms of efficiency and practicality?

```
//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?format=png&key***********************&maptype=roadmap&sensor=false&size=500x350&zoom=10&style=feature:all%7Celement:all%7Chue:0xff1a00%7Cinvert_lightness:true%7Csaturation:-100%7Clightness:33%7Cgamma:0.5&style=feature:water%7Ccolor:0x2d333c%7Cfeature:geometry%7Ccolor:0x2d333c&path=fillcolor:0xfff5f0%7Ccolor:0xFFFFFF00%7Cenc:jyycP{h}tEjnGefArAyBL]pAaDxA_ERe@pA{ClBqDFMnC_Ef@i@jCwCp@g@xDwCDE~DaCvAw@fBcA|DqBRKjDcBfD{AVM~DcB|CmA`@O|D{A~DoAJErDiA~DqAnAc@nBg@|DcA~D_A`AS|BM~DS|DW~DW~D[~D[~D_@tBWfAM~Dw@~D}@~Dy@JArDe@|DS~DG~DE~DC|DE~DO~De@`Dw@\K~DiBfBkAtAcAdC{Bx@k@~DmCFEvDoB|BqA`Ac@|DqBz@i@bCmAjDqBRK~D{BrAy@jBq@|Di@~Dx@vA`@fBp@~DdA|Dv@lAPpBZ~Db@~D\~DZ|DV~DVnDTN@~DX~DZ|DX~DX~DF~DG|DY~Di@vCg@f@I~Dq@~Do@|Dm@jDe@RC~Dg@~Dc@~Dc@|Di@lAc@pBaAxC}Bd@_@j@e@nIsk@jSwuAr`@iuChD{VrEm|@eHmpBwAa@_EcAqD{@MC_E_A_E}@}D}@A?}D_A_E{@_Eu@y@McCi@_E}@sCyAk@i@cBuC{AqC]m@iCaEW[uCcDg@i@{DuCCC_EmB}DoAA?_E{@}Dm@_E]_EU_EK_EC}DE_EK??_EU_E]}D]_Ec@_Ei@kD_@SC_ES}D?_ETG@wDT_EP_EN}DP_EN_EH_EB}DA_EG_EK_ES_EW}D[w@IgCe@_EcA_EiAa@M}CmA}DuAcA[{B_A_EqAgCm@w@W_E_A}Do@_E]_ES_EC}DD_EN_EV_EBqBu@mAi@}DoA_Eo@}CUa@C_EK_EB}DJC?{DP_EX_E`@}Dd@_El@iB\uAT_Ev@_E`AgBp@uAb@_EzB_@^{B~Dc@b@_EtA_E^}DN_EJ_EQ_Ew@}DqAu@YiCqAeDmBYS_EeDEEiDaEOS{BkDaA{AmAcBqBeC}@{@aCqBmBmAqAs@_E}AeCm@w@S_Ee@_EY_EU_EQ}DO_EO_EO_EQi@CsCM_EY_Ea@_Ek@_Es@gAUuBc@_EeA_EoAOEoDoA_EyAm@WoCaA_EuAyAg@eBi@_EoAuDeAGC_EaA_E{@{C_Ac@Q_EkCe@a@wCmDQQcCaEi@mAaAqBsA_Ei@_CWaAo@_EY_ECaET_Ex@_ETo@hAqCtBeDVYfDuCbAi@xBaA~DiAlDu@PC~D}@~DaAjD{@PE~DeA~DeAzBm@bAY|DgA~DiAp@UlCw@~Dk@~DR|D^~Dd@n@HnC^~Df@~Df@|Dh@zDf@B?~Dd@~Db@|Db@~D^~D\vBRfAH~DT|DN~DN~DF~DD~D?|DE~DI~DK~DQ~DUvAIdBO|AOaaDsQmqEeUojNur@weAoFcAr@qB`BkAdAoCxBo@h@_EtC?@_EnCaAn@}BxAkCdBq@b@_E`Ci@XuC`BqC~Am@^}D|CA@{C~Da@v@wAhCcB~DCFmAvDeA`Ek@xB[dAiA~DmA`EKZeAbDwA~D_@dA}@zBeB~D[r@qAjCmBxDCFcC~Dw@lA{ApBcBnBsApAiBvAoCfBo@\_EhBwBv@gA\_E~@}Dr@_Ej@SBkDZ_ER}DD_Es@EAyDkBaCuA}@k@_EeCSMiDyBgBeAwA}@_EaCAA}D}BeBaAyAy@}D{BQImDoBaCqAMGpf@vtBlKz_@rrAx{EvbA`rDj@kA~@_Eh@eCNy@r@aEn@_Eh@_E^aDD_@b@_E\_E\aEV_EV_ETaERsD@KT_EVaE\_E`@_Ef@aEf@_DF_@t@_E|@aEbAwD@GpA_E~AaEJQbBmDxAeCh@y@tCuDHKtDqDNMnDcC|A{@`Bq@|DoA~Dy@TEhDi@~Dq@|Do@~Dq@BAzDs@~Dw@~D{@tAWfB_@~Dw@~D}@fCk@v@Q~Ds@|Di@~D[~DO~DE~DF|DP~D\~Dj@~Dv@TDfD|@~DpAbBp@zAn@~DnBr@^jCzAvCbBd@Z~D|B|@f@`CvA~CfB^T~D`C|@f@~BxAtCfBh@^~DhC^T~CxB|AdA~AlArCrBj@b@~DvCBBzDvCp@f@lCrBzAlA`BpA~BlB~@r@dDjCXT~DbDFFvDlDVPdD|BfB`AvA|@~DxBNHnDhBnCtAn@Z|DhBtBx@hAd@~DjA~Dz@z@R`Cd@~Dt@~Dp@fDp@VDnDxDNrD?L??cC~D{@dAuBxBiAtAcBjB{AhBgAtAwBjCi@r@sClDORgD~DGH_DtD_@b@uC|Ci@f@aDvC[X_EdDA?}DbDa@\}CdCaAx@}BjBkBrAqA`AyD~BEB_EvB_CbA_Ab@_ErA}D|@q@HmC^_EP_EB_EE}DQ_E[EAyDc@_Eg@}Di@_Eg@gDa@WC_E_@_EW}DW_E[_E]_Ea@oBOoAK}DS_EM_EO_EO}DQ_EY_Ec@eCc@y@I_E_@}DI]r@B`EG~D_@~D_B`E]Z_Ex@_E`@_E^}DXaBL}AJ_EZ_Eb@_El@}Dt@s@NkCn@_EfA_E|@_@J}Cp@_Ex@_Ez@oAVoB`@_ElAuBnAgAbAKLd[liAp[hjAbZrfAfVj|@xApCno@vmAjq@dPfr@pDrbAqJft@aH|z@eIhUyBtqD}m@
```

This is one of the requests. It is over 2k chars.

Comment: long and multiple parameters? can you please show an example?

Comment: Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You can't trigger a screen shot on the user's machine from Ruby or Rails directly. You could do it using other tools. I'd suggest starting with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60455/take-a-screenshot-of-a-webpage-with-javascript?lq=1 and reading the linked pages.